# Compile Rails application to static site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know if there is a way (or a gem) that can compile me a Rails application into a static web site; I have some files that need to only be compiled once (i.e. they have no dynamic content but they need to be parsed at least once). I can't seem to find any way to do that so I have a feeling that it might not even be possible.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I get it but if you want to export static html and css files from a website, you could use wget in a terminal.

Comment: What I want to do is to have a Rails application that has Rails semantics in it but with no actual dynamic content (no interaction with a database) and get it compiled to a static html site. Hope that makes is clearer.

Comment: Rails doesn't really do static only sites out of the box. You can probably use something like HighVoltage, and move your views over to it's pages controller. https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage

Comment: use [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com)!

Comment: a tool to perform such a task has been there in most unix/linux operating systems for decades. its called `cURL`. Rolling your  custom `perl` or `ruby` script using `cURL` should not be a big task. Note: Tools for download a website for offline reading have been there for years. BTW, have you looked at this https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/static_website_generation

Comment: Unfortunately no! But thanks I'll check it out! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to do that with an entire Rails app. That's more the territory of https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll or https://github.com/imathis/octopress. If it's only a few pages you can use `caches_page :page1, :page2, ...` in your controllers. That will write the fully-rendered page to `public/` so that it can be served directly by Nginx/Apache on subsequent requests.

**Edit** In Rails 4 you'll need to use the `actionpack-page_caching` gem.

Comment: I'll try the caching method and retrieve the results! Also high-voltage sounds quite nice since it's only for a few pages.